# Command line scripts in python package: Do they work on windows machines or only on Linux?

Tags: python, powershell, command-line, package, setuptools

I'm experimenting with command line scripts on a windows machine as explained [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html). I created a simple python package as follows:

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 986C-80E1
C:.
│   setup.py
│
├───bin
│       funniest-joke
│
└───funniest
        funniest.py
        __init__.py
```

I list the contents of each file below for reproducibility:

## `setup.py`

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
  name='test',
  scripts=['bin/funniest-joke'],
  packages=setuptools.find_packages()
)
```

## `bin/funniest-joke`

This is the command line script:

```
import funniest
print(funniest.joke)
```

## `funniest/funniest.py`

`joke = "a funny joke"`

## `funniest/__init__.py`

`from .funniest import joke`

When I run `pip install -e .` the package installs successfully. However, running the script directly by typing `funniest-joke` in the command line and then "Enter" doesn't work. I get the windows menu asking how I would like to open the file:

[image]

Are command line scripts in python packages strictly a Linux thing? How can I get this to work on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely not the answer you're going to like: Windows works by associating file extensions to execution methods. The problem is: `funniest-joke` has no file extension, so Windows doesn't know what execution method it should invoke to execute the file. So, it asks you. (What you want to do: write a PowerShell or CMD wrapper script that invokes `python` directly.)

Linux looks at the first line of the file (or first `n` bytes, e.g. 512 to 4096 bytes) to determine an execution method. Scripts have a shebang, "`#!`". Native machine executables have a different signature. If you really want to get into the details, look at the source code for the `exec` system call, or look at the `file` command's manual page.

Comment: I hear you... but command line scripts are built-in python functionality. Why does `setuptools`  not check which platform I'm on and handle it accordingly?

Comment: Command line scripts are not Python functionality. They are a function of the operating system's command interpreter and executive functionality. `setuptools` could automagically generate a wrapper script, but that complicates things tremendously.

Comment: Here's a good reason why `setuptools` shouldn't automagically generate a wrapper on Windows: too many choices for command interpreters (CMD vs. PowerShell). On Linux, you're guaranteed to have `/bin/sh`. Always. PowerShell and CMD are different enough to make this a maintainer's headache.

Comment: Allright... I believe you. But then I'm lost as to how to best experiment with stuff *while* developing a package. Say I just wanted to play around with some code which I don't want to be part of the modules I import for the time being, is there a conventional/best-practices way to do that?

Comment: Windows: `python code.py`. :-)

Comment: Ok, that's not the most entertaining answer. You could work within one of the many IDEs (Sublime, VS Code, Idle, ...) Or work within `python` directly -- you import the module the first time you use it, then you have to reload it (there are a few ways to do that) to pick up your changes.